# How to check using python boto3 if AWS account is in sandbox mode for SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses, amazon-simple-email-service

I am writing a Lambda Function in Python, which will use AWS SES for sending emails.

However, in my test AWS account, I don't want to send emails to real users.

So I wanted to perform a check like this,

if Account_Status = SANDBOX, then send emails to a pre-verified default recipient. (e.g. an internal company email address )

if Account_Status = PROD, then send emails to the real user email addresses.

But I couldn't find any related boto3 method in ses client, which can give me Account Status.

I tried `response = client.get_account_sending_enabled()`  but it returns  `true` even if account is in sandbox..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the sesv2 api instead which has a flag directly defined in the response of the [get_account()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sesv2.html#SESV2.Client.get_account) function.

```python
client = boto3.client('sesv2')
response = client.get_account()
print(response['ProductionAccessEnabled'])
```

From the documentation:

> ProductionAccessEnabled (boolean) --
>
> Indicates whether or not your account has production access in the
> current Amazon Web Services Region.
>
> If the value is false , then your account is in the sandbox . When
> your account is in the sandbox, you can only send email to verified
> identities. Additionally, the maximum number of emails you can send in
> a 24-hour period (your sending quota) is 200, and the maximum number
> of emails you can send per second (your maximum sending rate) is 1.
>
> If the value is true , then your account has production access. When
> your account has production access, you can send email to any address.
> The sending quota and maximum sending rate for your account vary based
> on your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks . This helped.